# Send Email Alert a day after due date

Tags: email, visual-workflow, process-builder, administration, email-alert

I have a requirement where I need to send out email to assigned user if Task is still open and it is after due date. I only managed to do the first part but now I'm a bit lost on the due date part.. Is this possible through Flow?

Comment: record-triggered flows with scheduled paths

Comment: You have a variety of options, including time-dependent workflow or scheduled actions in either Process Builders or Flows.  You should be able to find many tutorials using these search terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use time dependent workflows to send email based on the due date or a few days after/before due date.

[Refer this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000340084&type=1&mode=1)